# Jquery Datatables only updates half of my data in database sql using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, codeigniter, datatables

Help. I cant seem to make my code work. It only limits me to update 300 data. I am using CodeIgniter. Is there something wrong in my htaccess or in my model?

Here is the UI:

[image]

Here are the 330 products :

[image]

I dont know why it only updates 300 data

Here is my code in the js datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#table').DataTable({
 "bJQueryUI": true,
 "bProcessing": true,
 "processing": true,
 "bDeferRender": true,
 
 ajax: window_location+'/htdocs/reconciliation_items1',
 columns: [
   {
    mRender: function(row, setting, full){
     return "<input type='hidden' name='unitPrice[]' value='"+full.unitPrice+"'>"+"<input type='hidden' name='itemNum[]' value='"+full.itemNum+"'>"+
       "<input type='hidden' name='ph_id[]' value='"+full.ph_id+"'>"+full.prodName;
    }
   },
   {
    mRender: function(row, setting, full){
     return full.prodQty + ' units';
    }
   },
   {
    mRender: function(row, setting, full){
     return "<input name='physical_count[]' type='number' min='0' step='1' class='physical_count' >" +
      "<input name='status[]' type='hidden'>" +
      "<input name='computed[]' type='hidden'>" +
      "<input name='initial[]' type='hidden' value='"+full.prodQty+"'>";
    }
   },
   {
    mRender: function(row, setting, full){
     return "<label class='status'></label>";
    }
   },
   {
    mRender: function(row, setting, full){
     return "<textarea name='remarks[]' class='remarks'></textarea>";
    }
   }
   ],
 scrollX: true,
 columnDefs: [{targets: 0, width: '100px'}, {targets: [1,2,3,4], width: '50px'}],
 ordering: false,
 bPaginate: false,
 language: {
  info: 'Total number of products: <b> _MAX_ </b>',
  infoEmpty: 'Total number of products: <b> 0 </b>'
 }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/submit.js'></script>
```

Comment: check max char set for post method. its usually 1024 range. change that to suit your application

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy ill change it in my htaccess?